# Can I get the following results without loops and just using matrix operations

Tags: python, torch

I want to get the following results like the output show, Can I make it without for loop and just using matrix operations like numpy or torch, thanks all.

```
import torch

torch.manual_seed(0)
input = torch.rand((1,3543,768))
w = torch.rand((3543,768,1))
output = torch.zeros(input.shape[0], input.shape[1], 1)

for i in range(input.shape[1]):
    output[:, i, :] = torch.matmul(input[:,i,:], w[i,:,:])
```

output:

```
tensor([[[0.4963, 0.7682, 0.0885,  ..., 0.1497, 0.3923, 0.9338],
         [0.1164, 0.3539, 0.6640,  ..., 0.5025, 0.4458, 0.2083],
         [0.3337, 0.6611, 0.7212,  ..., 0.0513, 0.3007, 0.8048],
         ...,
         [0.5168, 0.3856, 0.0275,  ..., 0.6173, 0.8562, 0.8301],
         [0.8208, 0.1885, 0.4760,  ..., 0.4657, 0.4911, 0.2394],
         [0.8758, 0.9653, 0.8739,  ..., 0.7802, 0.1038, 0.4542]]])
```

Comment: That's not the output you would get.  That's going to produce a (1,3543,1) array.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it

```
output = torch.einsum("bij,ijk->bik", input, w)
```